# Golang Transform JSON

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I am working on Golang, GORM to Implement API using Echo Framework

I am using following struct and function to generate JSON

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string 
}

func GetUsers(c echo.Context) error {
    db := db.GetDBInstance()
    users := []model.User{}
    db.Find(&users)
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, users)
}
```

Here is my JSON response

```
[
 {
  ID: 1,
  CreatedAt: "2020-04-21T05:28:53.34966Z",
  UpdatedAt: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  DeletedAt: null,
  name: "",
  username: "test",
  Password: "test123"
 }
]
```

I want to convert it into following JSON

```
{
  data: [{
   ID: 1,
   CreatedAt: "2020-04-21T05:28:53.34966Z",
   UpdatedAt: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
   DeletedAt: null,
   name: "",
   username: "test",
   Password: "test123"
  }]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You expected JSON is invalid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new struct to do this

```
type Data struct{
    Data []model.User `json:"data"`
}

func GetUsers(c echo.Context) error {
    db := db.GetDBInstance()
    users := []model.User{}
    db.Find(&users)
    data := &Data{
        Data: users,
    }
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create helper to handle the response, like:

helper/response_formatter.go

response struct:

```
type Response struct {
    Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

response formatter function:

```
func ResponseFormatter(data interface{}) Response {
    response := Response{
        Data: data,
    }

    return response
}
```

invoke the function

```
import helper

...

response := helper.ResponseFormatter(users)
```